# Swap function using void pointers

Tags: c, swap, void-pointers

I want to make a swap function that can be generically used for any data type. I know that the following function works for ints:

```
void swap(void *a, void *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *(int*)a;
    *(int*)a = *(int*)b;
    *(int*)b = temp;
}
```

and this works for strings:

```
void swap(void *a, void *b)
{
    void *temp;
    temp = *(void**)a;
    *(void**)a = *(void**)b;
    *(void**)b = temp;
}
```

Comment: This has already been answered.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232706/swapping-objects-using-pointers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass the size of the pointee along, too (like in `qsort`), then you can do it:

```
void swap(void * a, void * b, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char * p = a, * q = b, tmp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != len; ++i)
    {
        tmp = p[i];
        p[i] = q[i];
        q[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Qux x, y;
swap(&x, &y, sizeof(Qux));
```

(You might want to add `restrict` qualifiers to the pointers, or otherwise a test for self-swapping.)

Comment: Suboptimal, but straightforward!

Comment: There are types that are not trivially copyable, and with C lacking a copy ctor...

Comment: @chqrlie: Please post the optimal solution when you have it!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: there is no absolute optimal solution, it would depend on architecture, average lengths passed, inlining, compiler acumen... An inline function with extra tests on standard sizes might generate faster code at a small loss for generic cases.

Comment: Why bother with `restrict` ? Your code will handle self swapping correctly, albeit not optimally.  Swapping with an extra variable does not fail on self swapping like other methods involving xoring or subtraction do.

Comment: @chqrlie: Just to return early in case there's no work needed.

Comment: OK, only useful if self-swapping is quite common. If that's the case, the calling code does not deserve the extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/) at least once. It is good to see what people have pondered over time.

[Why can't I perform arithmetic on a void * pointer?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidparith.html)  is relevant to your question:

> The compiler doesn't know the size of the pointed-to objects. (Remember that pointer arithmetic is always in terms of the pointed-to size; see also question 4.4.) Therefore, arithmetic on `void *`'s is disallowed (though some compilers allow it as an extension). Before performing arithmetic, convert the pointer either to `char *` or to the pointer type you're trying to manipulate (but see also questions 4.5 and 16.7).

Also relevant is [Suppose I want to write a function that takes a generic pointer as an argument and I want to simulate passing it by reference. Can I give the formal parameter type `void **` ...](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html):

> There is no generic pointer-to-pointer type in C. `void *` acts as a generic pointer only because conversions (if necessary) are applied automatically when other pointer types are assigned to and from `void *`'s; these conversions cannot be performed if an attempt is made to indirect upon a `void **` value which points at a pointer type other than `void *`. When you make use of a `void **` pointer value (for instance, when you use the `*` operator to access the `void *` value to which the `void **` points), the compiler has no way of knowing whether that `void *` value was once converted from some other pointer type. It must assume that it is nothing more than a `void *`; it cannot perform any implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer:

```
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t width)
{
    void *temp = malloc(width);
    memcpy(temp, b, width);
    memcpy(b, a, width);
    memcpy(a, temp, width);
    free(temp);

}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY If `width` is the number of bytes to be allocated, why do you say it needs to be `sizeof width`? If we assume `size_t` is 4 bytes (e.g. as an example), then `memcpy` would only swap 4 bytes between `*a` and `*b`; wouldn't that be a problem if `a` and `b` point to something larger than `sizeof width`'s 4 bytes? Unfortunately, your comment is not informative at all, so I'd appreciate clarification.

Comment: @chqrlie Can you elaborate on your comment more, so that it's actually helpful as to _why_ that's the case? For example, it's not obvious where the leak is, particularly if `width` is the number of bytes to be allocated in the first place, or why the distinction between `width` and `sizeof width` is relevant here when `malloc` expects the number of bytes to be allocated rather than the size of the variable being used to specify it.

Comment: @code_dredd: sorry for the confusion, BLUEPIXY's and my comment addressed a mistake in the original answer code where Connor wrote `malloc(sizeof width)`, which was incorrect and caused undefined behavior if `width > sizeof width`. Connor fixed his answer but did not post a comment to make us aware of the fix and remove the obsolete comment.

Comment: @chqrlie Oh, ok, that makes total sense, b/c I wasn't seeing it. Thanks

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: your comment in obsolete :)