# void pointer swap function in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, swap, void-pointers

i wrote a func swap_pointers meant to replace the memory adresses both pointers point to.

meaning if before calling swap, `v_a` points to the `int a` and `v_b` to `b`, afterwards `v_a` should point at `b` , and `v_b` at `a`.

Running `main()`, I do see the adresses switch, and callng `printf()` indeed prints `6 8`, but when the lines

```
a = *((int *) v_a);
b = *((int *) v_b);
```

are executed, both vars (`a` and `b`) recieve the value `6`.
I can't understand why this is happening.

```
void swap_pointers(void **a, void **b){
  void * tmp=*a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

int main() {
  int a = 8;
  int b = 6;
  void *v_a = &a;
  void *v_b = &b;
  swap_pointers(&v_a, &v_b);
  printf("%d %d\n", *((int *) v_a), *((int *) v_b));
  a = *((int *) v_a);
  b = *((int *) v_b);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swapping objects using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232706/swapping-objects-using-pointers)

Comment: Note how this does not happen if you do `int new_a = *((int *) v_a);`
  `int new_b = *((int *) v_b);`. Why do you think that might be? :)

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you not using `std::swap(v_a, v_b);`?

Answer (score 4):

After you do the swap, `v_a` is pointing to the address of `b`, and `v_b` is pointing to the address of `a`.

Then, when you do:

```
a = *((int *) v_a);
```

you are actually assigning the value of `b` to `a` which makes it 6.

Then of course, when you do the assignment to `b` on the next line, you are assigning the new value of `a`, which is 6.

Answer (score 3):

After calling the function `swap_pointers`

```
swap_pointers(&v_a, &v_b);
```

the pointer v_a points to the variable b amd the pointer v_b points to the variable a.

After this statement

```
a = *((int *) v_a);
```

the variable `a` has the value `6`. The pointer `v_b` points to the variable `a` that at this time contains the value `6`.. So after this statement

```
b = *((int *) v_b);
```

the variable `b` will get the value stored in the variable `a` obtained in the precedent assignment statement that is the same value `6`.

To swap the values in the variables `a` and `b` you need to use an intermediate variable or to write one more function that swaps values in objects of the type `int`.

For example

```
void swap_integers( int *a, int *b )
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

The function can be called like

```
swap_integers( v_a, v_b );
```